# CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Capsule not extracted. while processing system property java.io.tmpdir: /tmp (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)

Tags: java, corda

After running this **`command java -jar corda.jar.`** I am getting this error:

```
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Capsule not extracted. while processing system property java.io.tmpdir: /tmp (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
```

Comment: it is hard to say, try setting the extra cmd line property `java -Dcapsule.log=verbose -jar corda.jar` should do so and see what the extra information says.

Answer (score 1):

So with only the information here it's hard to have any clue what the issue is.

It's possible you have a bad download so I'd say to just download a newer version of the corda jar and give it another try with the verbose flag to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to launch my application. Checking the contents of the error with `-Dcapsule.log=verbose`, java complained that it could not clean the temporary folder. After a quick check I found an instance of the application was **running in the background**, which prevented cleaning. Closing  this instance solved the issue.